# How to find the Minimum number of swaps required for sorting an array of numbers in descending order in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get my code to do this:

Original array = [1,2,3,4] swap once-> [4,2,3,1] swap again->[4,3,2,1]

Therefore result is 2

But it's not working. Here's what I have so far:

```js
   

 function check(arr){
 var sarr = [];
 var cnt = 0;
 var arrL = arr.length;
   // Create a second copy of the array for reference
 var arrCopy = [...arr];
 for(let i=0; i<arrL;i++){
  var maxV = Math.max(...arr);
  sarr.push(maxV);
  let pos = arr.indexOf(maxV);
  // Remove the found number
  arr.splice(pos,1);
  // Check if the index of the number in the new array is same with the copy, if not then there was a swap
  let ai =arrCopy.indexOf(maxV); 
  let si =sarr.indexOf(maxV);
  if (ai !== si && (i+1)!=arrL && pos !== 0){
  cnt++;
        };
 }

 console.log(cnt);
}

check([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);//Result should be 3
check([6,5,4,3,2,1]); //result should be 0

check([1,2,3,4]); //result should be 2

check([1,3,2,5,4,6]); //result should be 3

check([1,2,10,4,5,6,7,8,9,3,12,11]);//result should be 6

check([ 49, 37, 9, 19, 27, 3, 25, 11, 53,  42, 57, 50, 55,  56, 38, 48, 6, 33, 28, 8, 20, 31, 51, 14, 23, 4, 58, 52, 36, 22, 41, 47, 39, 2, 7, 13, 45, 1, 44, 32, 10, 15, 21, 30, 17,  60, 29, 5, 59, 12, 40, 24, 54, 46, 26, 43, 35, 34, 18, 16]);//result should be 54
```

Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look around and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). We need a much more complete and clear explanation of the goal.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. According to your example, can I assume that the original array must have been sorted in ascending order? What is the algorithm that you are going to sort the array in descending order?

Comment: The array can be in any order, if it is already in descending order then count should be 0.

Comment: I created a new array and assigned it the value of scrambled the array in descending order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would start with a copy of the array in descending order for getting the right index of the items.

For practical reasons, (or just a shorter conception of the loop with including check and decrement), I loop from the end of the array.

Then I check the value of `array` and `reversed` at the dame index and go on with the iteration.

If not the same value, the items at the wanted position `i` and the actual position `p` are swapped and the count incremented.

At the end the count is returned.

```js
function check(array) {
  var reversed = array.slice().sort((a, b) => b - a),
      count = 0,
      i = array.length,
      p;

  while (i--) {
      if (array[i] === reversed[i]) continue;
      p = array.indexOf(reversed[i]);
      [array[i], array[p]] = [array[p], array[i]];
      count++;
  }
  console.log(...array);
  return count;
}

console.log(check([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])); // 3
console.log(check([6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])); // 0
console.log(check([1, 2, 3, 4])); // 2
console.log(check([1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6])); // 3
console.log(check([1, 2, 10, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 12, 11])); // 6
console.log(check([ 49, 37, 9, 19, 27, 3, 25, 11, 53,  42, 57, 50, 55,  56, 38, 48, 6, 33, 28, 8, 20, 31, 51, 14, 23, 4, 58, 52, 36, 22, 41, 47, 39, 2, 7, 13, 45, 1, 44, 32, 10, 15, 21, 30, 17,  60, 29, 5, 59, 12, 40, 24, 54, 46, 26, 43, 35, 34, 18, 16])); // 54
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation, I apologize for the lack of structure of my question, it's my first time on stackoverflow.

Comment: how to do this in java ? minimum swaps required to sort the array in descending order

Comment: @asinha, sorry no java.

Answer (score -1):

```
function minimumSwaps(arr) {
  var count = 0;
  arr.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a < b) {
      count++;
    }
  });
  return count;
}

console.log(minimumSwaps([1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6, 5]));
```

Comment: Please dont just post a codeblock and thats it, its better to put an explanatory text above or below to explain the solution better